# Оптимизация алгоритма "Найти наибольший палиндром от произведения двух простых пятизначных чисел"

Tags: java

```
Алгоритм работает исправно:
для 2-digit numbers, ответ находит моментально;
для 3-digit numbers тоже отлично, но чуть дольше ищет ответ;
Для 4-digit numbers ответ ищет около 2-х минут(что не мало);
Для 5-digit numbers ответ ищет уже больше двух часов!!!

Вопрос: как оптимизировать код и улучшить производительность? Сделать 
так, чтобы для 5ти(и больше)-значных чисел ответ возвращало быстрее?

Ниже собственно код программы:

    public class Palindrome {

    private static final boolean reverse(long value) {
        String str = String.valueOf(value);
        return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }

    private static final boolean isPrime(int n) {
        int i;
        for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i= 0;
        int maxPrimeNumber = 99999;
        int minPrimeNumber = 10000;

        outer:
        for (i = maxPrimeNumber; i >= minPrimeNumber; i--) {
            for (int j = maxPrimeNumber; j >= minPrimeNumber; j--) {

                if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(j)) {
                    long cast = ((long)j)*i;
                    if (reverse(cast)) {
                        System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", i, j, cast);
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Если вы проверили пару i=10000, j=99999, то пару i=99999, j=10000 проверять уже не надо. Выигрыш уже в два раза. Проверка праймов может производится до sqrt(n), а не до n/2. Проще один раз составить таблицу всех простых чисел и брать числа только из нее.

Comment: изменил проверку в праймах - прирост к показателю быстродействия заметен. на счет создать один раз таблицу, то это конечно рабочий метод, но не очень спортивный, как по мне:) а на счет проверки пар, не до конца понял...как эту проверку сократить до 1 пары?

Comment: Ну если вам таблица - не спортивный метод... :-) Попробуйте для j условие пока оно больше i.

Comment: понял, благодарю вас за помощь +++ вам в карму)

Comment: Это спортивный метод и он называется решето Эратосфена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Оптимизируем нахождение простых.

```
private static final boolean isPrime(int n) {
        int i;
        if (n==1) return false;
        if(n=2||n==3)return true;
        if (n%2==0) return false;
        for (i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

2) Оптимизируем цикл

```
for (i = maxPrimeNumber; i >= minPrimeNumber; i--) {
             if(isPrime(i))
            for (int j = i; j >= minPrimeNumber; j--) {

                if ( isPrime(j)) {
}
```

isPrime теперь вызывается 1 раз для каждого i.

Comment: Это то, что нужно.